# Вставка блока кода в страницу

Tags: javascript, php

Я пишу PHP сайт. На странице есть блок "Продолжать/Скрыть" текст. Это я написал так:

```
<div id="myText"> Мой текст</div>
<p id="listSwitch" class='host_js'>Продолжать...</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myText').fadeOut(0000);
        $('#listSwitch').toggle(function () {
            $('#myText').fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).text('Скрыть')
        }, function () {
            $('#myText').fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).text('Продолжать...')
        })
    });
</script>
```

Только я этот код добавил прямо в `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`, в мою база данных. Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы я смог код добавить прямо из админки. Только чтобы я каждый раз ее не руками писал бы, а ну, может, через кнопку можно было ее ставить.

Comment: Вот объясните, как можно садится за написание проектка, не зная основ? Это всё равно, что начать строить машину, не понимая принципа работы двигателя. Мол, как колёса крутятся знаю, а дальше разберемся :(

Comment: после прочтения вопроса (раз 10) у меня взникло чувсто тревоги и непреодолимое желание нажать на соответствующую кнопку...

Comment: Не удержался. @Hmayak, перепишите, пожалуйста, вопрос, используя правила русского языка и кнопку 101010 для форматирования кода.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы тебе не геморроиться с БД и php.

Посоветую самую малость.

Берешь этот код

```
<div id="myText"> Мой текст</div>
<p id="listSwitch" class='host_js'>Продолжать...</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myText').fadeOut(0000);
        $('#listSwitch').toggle(function () {
            $('#myText').fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).text('Скрыть')
        }, function () {
            $('#myText').fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).text('Продолжать...')
        })
    });
</script>
```

Вставляешь его в блокнот, Ворд - любой текстовый редактор. Сохраняешь! И по надобности copy/paste.

**Самое отличное решения для тебя. ;)**

Comment: Ну спасибо, как я об этом не подумал. Ребята, мне кажется если у вас нету ответа, просто не надо не чего сказать. Мне казалось что здесь нормальные программисты отвечают, но видно это не так. Просто наверняка вы адрес на браузере не то собрали.

Comment: Для тех кто будет читать этот ответ, акцентирую ваше внимание:

Самое отличное решения **для тебя**. ;)

Comment: >Просто наверняка вы адрес на браузере не то собрали.
wtf!?

Comment: Я в ступоре, как быть что делать 

>если у вас нету ответа, просто не надо не чего сказать

>росто наверняка вы адрес на браузере не то собрали.

+1 к @Vitalii Maslianok  полный WTF!!!

Comment: Компилирование и сборка URL в адресной строке - высшая степень профессионализма программиста.